# Gentiles marriage

Tags: halacha, noachide-laws

Gentile couples are under what rules or laws regarding marital rights and duties compared to the onah laws of Judaism such as sexual attendance, food, clothing and whether it is a man's duty to provide for his wife including her giving him all equal income happens in Judaism? Are they valid or do they have different legislation? Do the seven Noahide laws address this issue in depth? Thank you if you clarify me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rabbi Moshe Weiner’s ‘The Divine Code’ (2020) is, to my knowledge,  considered the authoritative code when it comes to the Noachide laws. Part VI treats of laws pertaining to sexual relations, and relations between man and wife. This part is about 80 pages long, and it is too difficult for me, at present, to summarize. I can give you a few things that caught my eye, however: (1) A Gentile is not always obliged to marry and have children; he or she is exempted from this mitzvah if either thing would be too troubling or burdensome for them; (2) A Gentile husband is not obliged to provide for his wife and children, or have relations with his wife regularly, unless these things are part of the marriage contract or are part of the laws of the land in which they reside; (3) a Gentile man and woman are to be judged married, even without a wedding ceremony, if they have lived together for an extended period of time, and therefore the woman becomes forbidden to another man, wedding ceremony or not...

I’m sorry that I am unable give any more than that at this time. I hope this points you in the right direction!

Comment: It will help me a lot that you have informed me the source for these questions, 80 pages will give me a good time to delve into them, thanks for helping me, I leave the question open if others want to detail something more about this subject.

Comment: I'm new here, I can only vote with 15 reputation, sorry :)

Comment: @Thales - sorry, just noticed that!

Comment: @Thales - P.S. The reason I am not refraining from melakhah today is because I am a Gentile. Please don't think me a renegade! :)

Comment: I'm also a gentile and if you hadn't spoken, you wouldn't have known that today they are celebrating the Jewish New Year, I just now paid attention :)

Comment: @Thales - thank you for your sensitivity :) As I suspect you have realized, you will get much more knowledgeable answers and responses on non-holidays, from people who know these matters far better than me. I hope you stick around to take advantage of this. Got to run now - thanks for chatting. Best wishes to you in your search for knowledge. TW

Comment: Apology for, and questions related to my answer and comments here, posted here: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5478/noachide-fielding-questions-here-on-yom-tov-an-apology-questions